# write a function that validates password

Tags: if-statement

I have to write a function that validates a password and returns true or false. It is only true if it is 8 characters, contains a number, a upper case letter, and a symbol.

This is what I have for my function file.

```
def validatepassword(pswd):

    for char in pswd:
        if char in '01234567890':
            containsnumber = True
```

I have no idea how to incorporate the other variables, any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Which Language?

Comment: What sort of symbols are allowed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def validatepassword(pswd):

    ## Declare the flags and set them to False
    containsNumber = False
    containsUpper = False
    containsSymbol = False
    for char in pswd: ## Loop through the characters of the password
        if char in '0123456789': ## Check if the character's a number
            containsNumber = True
        elif char in "ABCEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ": ## Otherwise check if the character's an uppercase letter
            containsUpper = True
        elif char not in "0123456789ABCEDFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz": ## Otherwise check if the letter isn't an alphanumeric character (i.e. a symbol)
            containsSymbol = True

    if containsNumber and containsUpper and containsSymbol and len(pswd) == 8: ## Were all of the checks passed?
        return True
    return False ## No need for an 'else' as the program will only reach this stage if it hasn't returned anything yet
```

Answer (score 0):

Use regular expression and check the password matching as below in python.

Check python documentation for more help https://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html

import re

def validatePassword(pswd):

```
P=re.compile('[\d\D]')
if(P.match(pswd)):
    print('TRUE')
else:
    print('FALSE')
```

validatePassword('super')